# How to avoid tripping a breaker

Tags: appliances, electricity, automation

I have a microwave (~1200W when running) and a fridge (~600W when starting, rough/approximate measurement) on the same circuit, and whenever they are both running, the circuit breaker (110V, 15A) trips. Is there any easy way that I can have the microwave always have power, but the fridge only have power when the microwave is NOT running (i.e. heating something)?

I have seen "energy saving" power strips that power stuff down unless when a device is on, but I need the opposite of those - any ideas that I can hack together?

P.S. #1 I am not really concerned about the fridge losing power suddenly or being unable to cool the stuff inside it for a few minutes while the microwave is running.

P.S. #2: I am looking for an automated way, I don't want to have to use a switch or something that requires manual intervention

Comment: Intriguing question... Haven't heard about such a device, but try searching for "load balancing" or "current based switch/limiter "

Comment: Are you on 110/120V power? At 230V, 15A should be plenty to run both.

Comment: @Hobbes yes, 120V

Comment: Maybe you should ask on [electronics.se] for advice on how to build such a device...

Comment: Vote to close because it's a wiring issue, there's no lifehack for inadequate house wiring.  Just the microwave is too much for a 15A circuit, never mind the same one that runs the refrigerator.

Comment: Use a different circuit for each appliance. The total for both will pop the breaker every time.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest, it is probably possible to rewire a standard current-sensing power strip so that the slave outlet is turned *off* when the master (microwave) outlet is drawing current. Most relays have single-pole-double-throw (SPDT) contacts, and switching the slave connection to the other side would work as desired.

If you'd rather make your own switch, a [schematic from Elliott Sound Products](https://web.archive.org/web/20150702092837/http://sound.westhost.com/project79.htm) should work. You could put a pilot lamp on the 12-v portion of the circuit to warn when the microwave can't be used, or just leave it out.

One possible issue, though: if the microwave starts *while the fridge compressor is already running*, back-pressure builds while the fridge is off and it might require a few minutes delay before restarting the motor. Repeatedly switching a fridge compressor motor on and off ([short-cycling](https://web.archive.org/web/20150528165252/http://lvhvac.com/cope_bulletins/17-1262.pdf)) **can damage it**; so add a large capacitor across the base and emitter of Q1 and a diode in series with the base to act as an ON time delay.

Comment: The fact that you can damage the fridge should indicate it is better to just use another circuit for one of the device.

Comment: The chance damage is unlikely unless the short-cycling is frequent. but the issue can be avoided with a timer on the strips, as is built into most modern air conditioners (appliances more likely to be manually cycled). If @user2813274 had the option of another circuit, one would hope s/he would have used it.

Comment: If one is lucky the current from the microwave light coming on when opening the door should be able to shut to fridge down before the magnetron kicks in.  Having a minimum OFF time for the fridge will solve the short cycling issue nicely.